# Upating mysql fields asynchronously with ajax when "Like" is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, prototypejs

The question is fairly simple. Whenever user clicks on "like" I want to use javascript to update the mysql database through ajax. I have tried all means bit have found nothing helpful.  I know I will also need a server side script but the ajax is the main issue.

Here is the counter code I set up.

```
 document.observe("dom:loaded", function()
{
  $("likeForumLink").onclick=processForumLike;

});


function processForumLike(event)
{

  var numberOfLikes=parseInt($("hiddenLikes").value); 

   numberOfLikes+=1;

  $("hiddenLikes").value=numberOfLikes+""; 

   this.innerHTML="You liked this"; 

  if(numberOfLikes==1)
  {
   $("numberOfLikes").innerHTML="("+numberOfLikes+" like)";

  }          
 else
 {
 $("numberOfLikes").innerHTML="("+numberOfLikes+" likes)";
 }

var likes=$("hiddenLikes").value;

new Ajax.Request("seeForum.php?id=$("subjectId").value", {

  method:'get', 
  parameters:{hiddenLikes:likes},      
  onSuccess: ????  //Don't know
  onComplete:???   //Don't know
  on Failure:????  //Don't know

 });
}
```

And then I can use my server side script as follows.
P.S. It lies in the same page `"seeForum.php?subjectId=$("subjectId").value"`

```
  <?php if(isset($_GET["hiddenLikes"]))
    {

     $updateQuery="UPDATE `subject table` SET  `likes`='".$_GET["hiddenLikes"]."' where `subjectId`='".$_REQUEST['subjectId']."' ";

     $result=mysql_query($updateQuery);

     checkConnect($result,"query of $updateQuery");


 ?>
```

Please help. All my work has come to a halt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using a GET request to update data, that should be a POST. And this:

```
"seeForum.php?id=$("subjectId").value"
```

doesn't do what you probably think it does. What it does do is cause a syntax error because it looks like `"x" x "x"` to the JavaScript interpreter and that's not JavaScript. I'm not sure which JavaScript library you're using ([Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) perhaps?) but I think you probably want to put all your parameters into `parameters` to avoid having to worry about URL encoding and things like. Furthermore, there's no reason to tell the server how many "likes" you already have and there is a good reason not to: someone might have "liked" the page while you're looking at some the number of likes you currently have will be wrong; so `hiddenLikes` isn't needed at all.

Something like this would be better on the JavaScript side:

```
new Ajax.Request("likeIt.php", {
  method:     'post', 
  parameters: { id: $('subjectId').value },
  onSuccess:  function(transport) {
      // Update the "likes" label with something like this,
      // I'm not that familiar with Prototype though so I'm
      // guessing.
      $('likes_label').update(transport.responseText);
  },
  onComplete: ????  // The function to call when it has finished.
  onFailure:  ????  // The function to call when it doesn't work.
});
```

And then, in the PHP, just send a simple UPDATE to the database to increment the number of likes in `likeIt.php`, something like this:

```
<?php
# Perform whatever authentication you need...
if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
    # Set up your database connection and then...
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `subject_table` SET `likes` = `likes` + 1 WHERE `subjectId` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]) . "'");
    # Check $result and send some data back to the client (if desired), if
    # you send something back then the onComplete, onFailure, and onSuccess
    # JavaScript functions would be responsible for doing something with it.
}
# Send back the updated number of "likes" as text/plain.
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your indepth and detailed answer. Your help has been essential for my work. Sorry, I am simply new and I don't know much about ajax So what I really want to do is submit my likes asynchronously to the database, without having to reload the page. Can you suggest what should I have in my `onSuccess` part?

Comment: btw, I am using prototype library.

Comment: @jbloom: I'm not that familiar with Prototype but I've updated things a little bit to (hopefully) point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks. You are right on the prototype. Only the `transporter` needs to be replaced with `ajax`. Do I even need `onSuccess` coz I think that if I can pass my likes in the parameters I may be able to UPDATE my table. The page site is `seeForum.php?subjectId=31` and if I am sending a like with it, then would it look like `seeForum.php?subjectId=31&likes=2` ?

Comment: @jbloom: I'm suggesting that you should move the AJAX handler to a separate PHP file that handles the AJAX and only the AJAX, you hand that just the `id`. You only need an `onSuccess` callback if you want to update the page with the new number of likes.

Comment: you see, i only want to update the number of likes in database when user clicks on `Like`. I don't know what to do with `ajax.responseText`. All I want is immediate access to new likes and store them in the database without reloading the page.

Comment: The `responseText` will have what `likeIt.php` sends back so `likeIt.php` can update the database, get the updated number of likes, and send that number back to the browser as plain text (just set the content-type to text/plain and print the number).

Comment: Understood. But what about ``LIKE`=`LIKE`+1` in the query area. Wouldn't that take place when even the page loads as default. Coz the id is still set which is true in every case (even when the user refreshes the page)

Comment: I moved that to a separate PHP file; one file to display the initial page, one to deal with the AJAX call; one file per function.

Answer (score 0):

Well thinking it through, if the user clicks on like, all you really want to do is increment the like counter in the page itself. You can do this in the `onComplete: function(){ increment the like counter }`. If some kind of error does occur, i don't think you would want to display it to the user, depends on how you want to handle that part, many ways to do it, you could log the error.